# Javascript eventlistener on key press makes toast message go away

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to modify a simple app. I have 2 text fields where a user can enter in a first or last name. If a user is found, that data is returned to a . If a user is not found, I have a toast message pop up saying, "a user cannot be found".

I'm trying to modify this, so if a toast message pops up and a user continues with a keypress the toast message will go away. The toast message should still occur if the user has finished input and does not press anymore keys.

Currently, the toast has a 5000ms default.

I have written some code. Here is my JS

```
var nurl="https://www.example.com/rest/5/query";
var gurl="https://www.example.com/rest/3/query";
var nameA=[];
var dt1;
var dt2;
var dataA;
var fnmarker;
var lnmarker;
var yposition;
var mrkr;
var ky;
var postreturn = $.post(); 
const toastContainer = document.querySelector('.toast-container');
const fNameInput = document.getElementById('fnameTB');
const lNameInput = document.getElementById('lnameTB');

fNameInput.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    
    if(e.key) {
        console.log('value of fnameinput ' + e.key);
        generateToast({show:'none'});
    }
})

lNameInput.addEventListener('keydown' , (e) => {
    
    if(e.key) {
        console.log("value of lnameinput " + e.key);
        generateToast({show:'none'});
    }   
});

function generateToast ({message, show}) {
    toastContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<p class='toast' style = 'display: ${show}'>${message}</p>`)
    const toast = toastContainer.lastElementChild;
    toast.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
        toast.remove()
    })
}

$(function(){
    window.scrollTo(0,yposition);
    addlayer();
});

function nameinput(){
    
    
    $("#nameresults").html("");
    postreturn.abort(); //abort ajax call
    if($("#lnameTB").val().length>2 || $("#fnameTB").val().length>2){
        var nm="name like '"+$("#lnameTB").val()+"%' and name like '%, "+$("#fnameTB").val()+"%'";
        
        postreturn=$.post(nurl,{where:nm,returnGeometry:false,f:"pjson",outFields:"*"},function(data){
            nameA=$.parseJSON(data);
            if(nameA.features.length<1){
                
                generateToast({message:'Unable to find the name you are searching for', show: 'inline'});
                
            }else{
                for(var i=0;i<nameA.features.length;i++){
                    $("#nameresults").append("<center><div class='d1' onclick='locateGrave("+i+")'>"+nameA.features[i].attributes.Name+"</div><div id='infodiv"+i+"' class='d2' onclick='closeinfo()'></div></center>");
                }
                
                if(window.innerHeight<$("#nameresults").height()){
                    $("#cover").css("height",$("#nameresults").height()+50+"px");
                }else{
                    $("#cover").css("height","100%");
                }
            }
        });
        
    }
    
}
```

I have my fNameInput and lNameInput text fields listening for any key down press. If there is a keypress detected, it calls my generateToast function with inline css that does style='display:none'. I was under the impression that this should hide my toast notification if a key down is detected.

When I test this in the browser and am able to generate my toast message and then continue to press buttons on the keyboard, nothing is hidden and more toasts generate with "unable to find the name you are searching for".

I've tried moving my fNameInput/lNameInput.addeventlistener inside the nameinput function and am not having the behavior that I'm expecting. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If the toast notification is a modal dialog, it prevents keyboard and mouse events from being sent to other elements on the page. So your listeners for the fname and lname fields don't run while the toast is displaying.

Comment: The toast notification was done purely with vanilla js and css. But if this constitutes a modal, I will have to possibly redesign this.

Thank you so much for you help!

Comment: We'd need to see the CSS for the `.toast` class. Does it use `z-index:` to make the toast overlay the rest of the page? I think that will make it modal.

Comment: you could simply add a keypress listener on the toast div that closes it.

Comment: Here is the css:

.toast {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  background-color: #989898;
  justify-content: center;
  animation: toasted 3500ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275) forwards;
}

Comment: So if you type while the toast is showing, is your input added to the field?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Every time you call `generateToast()` it creates a new toast popup. It doesn't do anything to the old ones.

Comment: Just do `toastContainer.innerHTML = '';` to remove all the old toasts.

Comment: This snippet of code handles removing old toasts.

const toast = toastContainer.lastElementChild;
 toast.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
  toast.remove()
 })
I'm almost certain, with the implementation I have that I cannot accomplish what I'd like to do.

Comment: That makes each toast go away automatically when its animation ends. It doesn't make it go away early when you type something.

Comment: Ok, the toastContainer.innerHTML = '' worked! Thank you so much!!!